# Pandas fastest way to count values based on multiple columns

Tags: python

Given a dataframe like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                   'c1' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
                   'c2' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']})
df
Out[5]: 
  id c1 c2
0  1  a  a
1  2  a  a
2  3  a  b
3  4  a  c
4  5  a  c
```

I want to add a new column with the count of values based on c1 and c2.
My current code is :

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'], dropna=False)['id'].transform('count')

df['result'] = np.where(df['count'] > 1, True, False)

df
Out[7]: 
  id c1 c2  count  result
0  1  a  a      2    True
1  2  a  a      2    True
2  3  a  b      1   False
3  4  a  c      2    True
4  5  a  c      2    True
```

Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a faster way, but the `np.where` is unnecessary, you can just do `df['count'] > 1`, which is faster to read :)
It won't change the speed of execution though, I think what you've got is already fast - is it not working fast enough?

```
In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: df['result'] = np.where(df['count'] > 1, True, False)
    ...: 
    ...: 
225 µs ± 16.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: df['result'] = df['count'] > 1
    ...: 
    ...: 
225 µs ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### EDIT

based on the answer below, `Counter` does seem to provide a speed-up:

```
In [27]: %%timeit
    ...: combined = df['c1'].astype(str)+df['c2'].astype(str)
    ...: df['count'] = combined.map(Counter(combined))
    ...: 
    ...: 
374 µs ± 6.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [28]: %%timeit
    ...: df['count'] = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'], dropna=False)['id'].transform('c
    ...: ount')
    ...: 
    ...: 
781 µs ± 38.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I need to use this code for ~150k lines and count values based on 20 columns and for the moment it's very long

Comment: @HenriMarteville can you try the Counter solution? Does that offer a speedup on your large data?

Comment: It's better :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(zip(df['c1'],df['c2']))
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c,orient='index', columns = ['count'])
```

From my `%%timeit` it seems to be one order of magnitude faster...

Comment: how would you create a new DataFrame column with this?

Comment: changed it to result to dataframe... In any case, unless you are doing something extreme, I advise you to go with something like what @Andreas proposes. But no matter what, avoid information duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
cols = ['c1', 'c2']
df = df.merge(df[cols].value_counts().rename('count'), on=cols, how='left')
df['result'] = df['count'].gt(1)
```